Gas Fireplace Smells & Flame Shutting Off
We are having issues with our Valor fireplace. It is very strange because it normally works fine during the day, but it typically does not work correctly in the evening or overnight (~4:30 PM - 6:00 AM). Sometimes the flame starts up and then slowly turns blue and dies out after about a minute. Other times, the flame does not die out, but it turns blue and the room begins to smell strongly of gas. Any ideas what could be going on? Thanks!

Turn off the gas to it and call an expert to check it out for gas leaks.  If you do not have a CO detector get one.  CO can kill you.  A build up of unburnt gas can go boom killing you and destroying your house.

@clvrmnky   You are right, but since not everyone knows about the dangers of CO gas and it tends to kill whole families as they sleep, I think we have a duty to mention it to each question.

"Blue" is actually good for natural gas flame. It is when it isn't blue that it is a sign of incomplete combustion - which can often mean CO issues. But in any case, it sounds like the burner is not burning all the gas - resulting in gas smell (the gas that doesn't get burnt) and poor flame quality (because the burner doesn't get enough gas in the right place.
